# pyrogram: get updates that happened during offline time

Tags: python, pyrogram, telegram-api

Assume that pyrogram client is started and receiving updates (new events) and saving them in a databse. if I stop the client, wait for one minute, and start the client again, it doesn't receive updates that occurred during the offline time.

by client, I mean a normal telegram account, not a bot.

Finally I found this page:
https://core.telegram.org/api/updates

Is there any function in pyrogram to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Pyrogram doesn't have this feature out of the box (July 2023). There is [an active issue](https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram/issues/263) on Github requesting such functionality.